# += operator overloading and cascading?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

For educative purposes, I wish to overload and use the += operator in cascade.

```
class a {
    public:
        a();
        a& operator+= (float f);
    private:
        float aa;
}

a() {
    aa = 0;
}

a& operator+= (float f) {
    aa += f;
    return *this;
}

a b;
b += 1.0; // Works.
b += 1.0 += 1.0; // Error : Expression must be a modifiable lvalue.
```

I don't understand why the above doesn't work (aside of the possible syntax mistakes -- didn't try to compile this sample code). Returning *this in the overloaded operator+= method, I would expect the second += 1.0 to be called on the b object, no?

Thanks.

Comment: You should post code without extra "fun" errors that are unrelated to the problem you are trying to illustrate.

Comment: Honestly I always did something like b += 1.0 + 2.0;

Comment: [Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). `+=` is evaluated right-to-left.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
b += 1.0 += 1.0;
```

The associativity for `+=` is right-to-left. So the above is interpreted as:

```
(b += (1.0 += 1.0));
```

Does that make sense? NO.

In order to make it work, you need to write it as:

```
(b += 1.0) += 1.0;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in order to have a `class a` with the least amount of surprise for its users, it's probably best to also define a member function

```
a& operator+=(a const&);
```

as well as non-member functions

```
a operator+(a const&, a const&); 
a operator+(a const&, float); 
a operator+(float, a const&);
```

that are each defined in terms of one of the member `operator+=` overloads. Then you can write

```
a1 += b1 + c1;
```

where `a1` is of type `a` the variables `b1`, `c1` can both be either `float` or `a`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/819272) from the [c++-faq](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) for more details.

Comment: `a operator+(a, a const&); ` is better than `a const&` version, isn't it?

Comment: @Nawaz Sure, but I had hoped to avoid the entire efficiency business and lvalue/rvalue discussion here, since you could also have 2 overloads for `operator+=` and 4 overloads of `operator+` with all the combinations of `a&&` and `a const&`. See e.g. https://github.com/d-frey/operators The point I am making here is that to "do as the ints do" requires at least a few overloads of `a` and `float` as well as an `operator+` to go along the single `operator+=`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the fine answers you got. You might be interested in converting constructors and/or conversion operators. For instance:

```
class a {
    public:
        a();
        a(float f);
        a& operator+= (float f);
        operator float() const;
    private:
        float aa;
};

a::a() {
    aa = 0;
}

a::a(float f) {
    aa = f;
}

a& a::operator+= (float f) {
    aa += f;
    return *this;
}

a::operator float() const {
    return aa;
}

int main()
{
    a b = 1.0;
    b += 1.0; // Works.
    b += (a)1.0 += 1.0; // Works.
}
```

or maybe better without conversion operator, but with `operator+=(const a&);`

```
class a {
    public:
        a();
        a(float f);
        a& operator+= (float f);
        a& operator+= (const a & x);
    private:
        float aa;
};

a::a() {
    aa = 0;
}

a::a(float f) {
    aa = f;
}

a& a::operator+= (float f) {
    aa += f;
    return *this;
}

a& a::operator+= (const a & x) {
    aa += x.aa;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    a b = 1.0;
    b += 1.0; // Works.
    b += (a)1.0 += 1.0; // Works.
}
```